# Where do I put common code for if and elif?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

For the example below:

```
 if a == 100:
     # Five lines of code
 elif a == 200:
     # Five lines of code
```

**Five lines of code** is common and repeating how can I avoid it?
I know about putting it a function

or

```
if a == 100 or a == 200:
    # Five lines of code
    if a == 100:
        # Do something
    elif a == 200:
        # Do something
```

Any other cleaner solution?

Comment: I would say the second solution is already fairly clean and simple.  Putting the 5 lines in a simple function would make it even cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that with functions, you can have local functions with a closure.  This means you can avoid passing repetitive arguments and still modify locals.  (Just be careful with assignments in that local function.  Also see the `nonlocal` keyword in Python 3.)

```
def some_func(a):
  L = []

  def append():
    L.append(a)  # for the sake of example
    #...

  if a == 100:
    append()
    #...
  elif a == 200:
    append()
    #...
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative (1): put your 5 lines in a function, and just call it

Alternative (2)

```
if a in (100, 200):
   # five lines of code
   if a == 100:
      # ...
   else:
      # ...
```

A little less verbose than your code

Comment: @paxdiablo: the `else` is just omitting the superfluous, so the usage of `in` remains. why is it hideous in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the dual-ifs (that's just a subjective thing, it's not gospel). I'd prefer refactoring any decent-sized commonality into a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def five_lines(arg):
  ...

if a in [100,200]:
    five_lines(i)
```

Comment: Did you mean `if` instead of `for`?